# Bing Maps - keep specific version

Tags: css, static, version, bing-maps

I'm using Bing Maps, and with CSS I'm styling the HTML-elements to get customized controls. I call version 7.0 of the script as seen below. However, it seems that the Bing team are making changes in what HTML-elements are returned from one 7.0-version to another. Now they have changed the class-names of the elements and my CSS is no longer working. I'm therefor wondering if there is a way to not only specify that I want to use version 7.0, but to be more specific so that I can get version 7.0.2011100111334.47 for example. Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
```

This does not seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0.2011100111334.47"></script>
```

Comment: This has started to hit us today. Seems the latest version served is 7.0.20111102162939.34, but *some requests get older versions*. As a result the map elements break intermittently as you refresh the page. FFFFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Comment: AARRRGH. Just refreshing the boot loading script at http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1 over and over yields *different versions*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No unfortunately there is not a way of doing this, Bing have said a number of times that they cannot support developers using undocumented/unsupported ways of customizing the map and don't therefore guarantee to not change how they do some things like div names.

Unfortunately this means if you want to do something that the API doesn't natively provide a way to do then you have to take the risk of it not working :-)

We have asked why we cannot target specific minor versions an the reply is usually based around them not wanted to have to support multiple versions which I can understand even if it makes advanced customization troublesome